# Error message: "no wi fi mac address"

Tags: wi-fi

I am trying to attach a smart power outlet on the smart phone app.  It updated the firmware and then tried to connect to wi-fi.  Nothing showed up in wi-fi and all I could do was add in a hidden network.  I tried adding in my network as a hidden network but it did not connect.  The only thing I have to go by is an error message indicating there is not a wi-fi mac address.

I am a newby, unlike the rest of you, so I am not sure what that means or how to fix it.  Is there anyone who has any ideas?  I really appreciate it, thanks.